# Hazlcast difference b/w IExecutorService & DurableExecutorService

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to evaluate performance b/w IExecutorService & DurableExecutorService.

I find that for same piece of code IExecutorService gives 25K TPS where as DurableExecutorService gives 300 TPS.

Is there any difference in their performance or am i missing some thing.

Execution Call back in DurableExecutorService also does not make any improvement.

Is there any other way in which i can ensure durability in Hazelcast.

Adding bit of code:

```
public class TransactionValidationTask implements Callable<Result>, DataSerializable, HazelcastInstanceAware {

public Result call() throws Exception {
    IMap<String, List<Events>> mapTranx = hz.getMap("transactionData");

    //Process data
    //Remove old events less than 15 mins
    //Store current event if its timestamp is greater that old events
    //generate alerts is any        

    return result;
}//Other methods omitted 

}
```

Calling the Callable in IExecutor / DurableExecutorService

```
final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

final IExecutorService executorService = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("MyExecutorService");
//final DurableExecutorService durableexecutorService = hazelcastInstance.getDurableExecutorService("default");
Thread processThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                if (!eventQueue.isEmpty()) {                
                    Event currentEvent = getEvent();
                    ExecutionCallback<Result> executionCallback = new ExecutionCallback<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        // Log for time being
                        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Error in executor service:" + t.getLocalizedMessage() + ", " + t.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Result result) {
                        //Process result

                    }
                }; 

                executorService.submitToKeyOwner(new TransactionValidationTask(currentEvent), currentTxn.getDeviceId(), executionCallback);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
        while(!executorService.isTerminated()) {}
    }
}
};
processThread.setDaemon(true);
processThread.start();
}
```

Comment: could you kindly share your «benchmark»? What's your use case?

Comment: @VikGamov Use case: gps tracking with geo monitoring & other alerts. I was testing the system with GPS events generated from 50 GPS devices. Thats when i found the performance difference b/w IExecutorService & DurableExecutorService.

Comment: Refined use case will be how executor service behaves when a node goes down and what happens to the existing tasks.

Comment: is there any POC code you can share? without real data. I would like to see APIs you use

Comment: @VikGamov Added bit of code.

Comment: @jbkhere can you post your benchmark so we can run it ourselves and investigate your findings ? Is it just the piece of code above ?
Also, the TransactionValidationTask are or equal to each other in terms of processing they do ? Performance in a distributed environment can vary a lot by many factors, eg. number of members, data locality, etc
You would want to strip down to a vanilla version of your benchmark, maybe just executing a pure math operation (1 + x) as a task for the executors on a single node setup, and keep a not of your findings. Then adding another node, and see what happens.

Comment: @VikGamov: Is there a way i can connect to via email

Comment: @Mr.tk is there a way in which i can connect with you. I can send entire code base. When tested in AWS r3.4xlarge 4 nodes i was able to hit a TPS of 160K for a single hazelcast client running in t2.xlarge. Another issue was when i connect with more clients the TPS drops by 40%